# Are there any "extended stay" or "multiroom suites" in hotels in England?

Tags: hotels, children, england

I'm from the US, and here there are a number of options for staying in a hotel which offer more than one adjoining room. Residence Inns are a great example where I can get a bedroom and a sitting room/kitchen or even 2 bedrooms with a central sitting room/kitchen.

This is great for my wife and me as we travel with our two kids and we can have separate bed rooms.

Now I'm booking a stay in southern England, near Portsmouth; and I can't find **anything close** to this. Most hotels are showing a "cap" of 2 people in the rooms, some don't even allow children.

Is anyone aware of anything like a multi-room suite, or an extended stay sort of hotel in England?

***EDIT***

Just as an example:  When I do [search for Marriotts](http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/pmeha-portsmouth-marriott-hotel/) (who owns Residence Inn) near Portsmouth and I put in the number of guests (4: myself, my wife, 2 kids) and 1 room, it comes back saying nothing like that exists:

[image]

If I enter 2 people, then they room is available, so clearly it's a problem that rooms don't accommodate more than 2 people... perhaps I need to call and confirm kids count as "people". 
(Note: the reason I don't want two separate rooms is because my kids are 2 and 3 years old, they need to be in the same unit as myself and my wife)

Answer (score 9):

In general: Yes, the sort of hotel you're looking for exists in England (arbitrary example, [there's a Staybridge Suites](http://www.ihg.com/staybridge/hotels/us/en/liverpool/lplkw/hoteldetail) in Liverpool), though it doesn't seem there are many in the Portsmouth area in particular. I'd suspect that they're less common in the UK in general, owing to the small overall geographic size of the country. Home is rarely more than a few hours away, which leads to fewer stays extending into the weeks or months category on which many extended stay hotels thrive. But that's just speculation on my part.

One resource that I find very useful when looking for 'Extended Stay' type rooms is the directory at [biz-stay.com](http://southampton-uk.biz-stay.com) (link goes to their Southampton/Portsmouth page specifically). In this case, it looks like your only real option is an executive room at the Holiday Inn Portsmouth (which is probably a double room, but likely lacks a kitchenette, in my experience); or looking into AirBNB or other short term apartment rentals.

Answer (score 9):

If you're looking for holiday/vacation accommodation in the UK which includes a kitchen and space for a family, one phrase to search for is "self-catering".

It's not so common for hotels to offer such amenities, but it is certainly possible (for example) [to rent a cottage](http://www.english-country-cottages.co.uk/) for a few days.

Comment: This can be a good option for staying in the UK as a family but be aware of the logistical implications. Especially if travelling without a car.

Comment: Most places won't let you get the keys until 2PM or so on the day of arrival and will expect you to leave by 10AM or so on the day of departure. Self catering means what it says, it's up to you to source all of your food. Many places require you to bring your own towels and some even require you to bring your own bed linen (or charge extra for renting it). Schedules are also often inflexible with most places strongly preffering to rent in weeks running from saturday to saturday.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [Marriott UK website](http://www.marriott.co.uk/residence-inn/travel.mi) Residence Inn by Marriott *ie Extended Stay Hotels* do exist in the UK but not in the Portsmouth area.

If you are currently in the US, I think your best bet would be to contact Marriott to explain your situation.

[Travelodge](http://www.travelodge.co.uk/) is a chain of hotels in the UK where all four family members can definitely stay in one room. This [example](http://www.travelodge.co.uk/hotels/479/Portsmouth-Hilsea-hotel) is for a Travelodge located in the Portsmouth area. As far as I'm aware Travelodge don't have rooms with a separate sitting area/kitchenette. If such hotel rooms do exist in the UK, which I think Residence Inn by Marriott do cater for, I'm sure you will pay top dollar for one.

Travelodge have a central reservations number where you could enquire:

+44 8719 848484

Answer (score 5):

Yes, many hotels provide for exactly this type of scenario.  The three types of things you need to look for are:

- Family rooms: often a king size plus two singles (or in our case a king size, two singles and a pull out bed, as we have 3 kids) Many hotels offer these
- Adjoining rooms: have 2 doors to the corridor, but an interconnecting door. These are very common.
- Suite - most of the better hotels offer suites with multiple bedrooms if required, or some may offer pull out beds or camp beds for children that can be set up in the living room or kitchenette areas in a suite

Answer (score 1):

So is a kitchen important ? Or are multi rooms important ?

I would recommend you use marriott.com as a yardstick to know if such hotels exist in England. I did a quick find for you in London : 2 Rooms 4 Guests and I assumed you'd need a kitchennete and found this in the marriott.com website : http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/lonql-grand-residences-by-marriott-mayfair-london/
So yes, I can see such hotels exist in England.

Similar search for Portsmouth returned this hotel : http://www.marriott.com/hotels/travel/pmeha-portsmouth-marriott-hotel/

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the way I'm searching for it... but when I check out that hotel (I have been on the site before) and try to find the rates for 1 room for 4 guests it says there's nothing available and I should check one of the hotels that can support this. They then link me to an Airport hotel (nowhere near Portsmouth)

Comment: I just noticed that you said a search of "2 rooms 4 guests". My assumption is that that would literally book 2 rooms, (ie two separate doors, two keycards). And I need more than one room, but with a single entry point from the hallway.

Comment: I agree this can get confusing. I remember choosing 2 rooms and 4 guests (4 of us adults) and being given a 2 bedroom suite. What you are saying, never crossed my mind. One other thing I did was to call their customer care and confirm this. May be you can call them and confirm before you book ? Just out of experience, if the rooms are running out - make the booking and then call them. There are no cancellation charges for a cancellation done 24 hours prior (in the USA).

Comment: I think your best bet will be to call their customer care for a booking. Or search for extended stays on one of the sites like orbitz

Comment: I just found this for you : Holiday Inn Express SOUTHAMPTON (Check-in: Sat, Sep 21, 2013 02:00 PM Check-out:
Sat, Sep 28, 2013 11:00 AM) Double room nonsmoking - Advance Purchase Savings, nonrefundable
Actual nightly rates
Sat  Sun  Mon  Tue  Wed  Thu  Fri
$194.20  $143.45  $158.79  $167.05  $167.05  $158.79  $158.79

Answer (score 1):

Most hotels in the UK offer **family rooms** for up to two adults and (typically) up to two children. It isn't clear from your post whether you specified in your search that the third and fourth guests were children rather than adults - perhaps that's why you didn't get good results?

In many cases a 'family room' will actually be a standard room where the sofa-bed has been folded out and made up as a second double bed. If you'd like a bit more space for spending time in the room during the day, you should be able to fold this bed away and use it as a sofa - either doing it yourselves, or asking the hotel to do it for you. I'd check with the hotel to confirm that this will definitely be possible though.

If you're keen on having separate bedrooms, for example so that you can put the kids to bed in the evening then sit and talk or watch TV without disturbing them, you'd probably prefer the interconnecting rooms option, which doesn't usually seem to be an option on booking websites so would need a call to the hotel to confirm, or to find a hotel offering suites as other answers have suggested. The common term for these here seems to be **apartment hotel**.